# How do I set a cell value using Apache POI for an adjacent column?

Tags: java, apache-poi

my goal is to iterate through an already existing Excel spreadsheet with 2 columns. One is called Manufacturer and the other is called DNC or Do Not Contact.

I want to loop through the list of manufacturers that I have and mark those that should not be contacted in red and in the adjacent blank column next to the manufacturer's name list some notes why they can't be contacted. I've attached my code below.

I store the fields of each manufacturer object in a linked list called "mu" and they are "name" and "DNC_Reason".

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator2 = spreadsheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator2.hasNext()) {
    Row row2 = rowIterator2.next();
    Cell DNC_Reason = row2.getCell(1);
    if(row2.getCell(1) == null) {
        row2.createCell(1);
    }
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator2 = row2.cellIterator();
    while (cellIterator2.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator2.next();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\.$|,|;|'|\\s|-]|\\b(LLC|Company|Incorporated|Co|Manufacturer|The|Limited|Ltd|Inc)\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(cell.getStringCellValue());
        String s = m.replaceAll("");
        for (Manufacturer mu : mfgs) {
            if (cell.getColumnIndex() == 0 && mu.getName().equals(s)) {
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
                DNC_Reason.setCellValue(mu.getDNCReason());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing your project. What is the issue you are experiencing and need help with?

Comment: Hi Michael. Basically I have 2 columns that I'm iterating through -- one already with a list of manufacturers and the other I plan on automatically filling with data called DNC Reason. The main problem I have is I get a null pointer exception when I try to run the program presumably because the cells to the right of the manufacturer names are blank.

Comment: Apologies for misspelling your name, Michiel. It's a bit late where I'm at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should create a map for your `not-to-be-contacted-manufacturers` with the name as key and the manufacturer as value. Then you can use `containsKey` instead of continually iterating over the `mfgs-list`.
2. You should iterate over the rows with the result of `rowIterator`. You don't need another iterator.
3. Local variables shouldn't start with capital letters (`DNC_Reason` - better name would be `dncReasonCell`)

Sample code assuming that the manufacturer cells are filled (`getStringValue()` might cause `NullPointerException` when no proper value is given), the style-variable is initialized and you have a not-to-be-contacted-manufacturers-map:

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = spreadsheet.rowIterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    Row row = rowIterator.next();
    Cell dncReasonCell = row.getCell(1);
    if (dncReasonCell == null) {
        dncReasonCell = row.createCell(1, CellType.STRING);
    }
    Cell manufacturerCell = row.getCell(0);
    String manufacturerNameForDncTest = Pattern
            .compile("[\\.$|,|;|'|\\s|-]|\\b(LLC|Company|Incorporated|Co|Manufacturer|The|Limited|Ltd|Inc)\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(manufacturerCell.getStringCellValue()).replaceAll("");
    if (notToBeContactedManufacturers.containsKey(manufacturerNameForDncTest)) {
        manufacturerCell.setCellStyle(style);
        dncReasonCell.setCellValue(notToBeContactedManufacturers.get(manufacturerNameForDncTest).getDNCReason());
    } else {
        dncReasonCell.setCellValue("");
    }
}
```